# Exercise 6.21 Isaacs's Character theory of finite groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, characters

> Let $1= H_0\lhd H_1\lhd\cdots\lhd H_n=G$. Assume that $H_i/H_{i-1}$ is nonabelian. Show that there exists $\chi\in Irr(G)$ with $\chi(1)\ge 2^n$.

*Hint* Use Corollary 6.17(Gallagher): Let $N\lhd G$ and let $\chi\in Irr(G)$ be such that $\chi|_N=\theta\in Irr(N)$. Then the characters $\beta\chi$ for $\beta\in Irr(G/N)$ are irreducible, distinct for distinct $\beta$ and are all of the irreducible constituents of $\theta^G$.

---

My attempt:

We can argue by induction on the length $r$ of the subnormal series. The base case is clear. Suppose it is true for all $r<n$, then for $r=n$, we notice that $H_n/H_{n-1}$ is non abelian implies there exists an irreducible character $\beta\in Irr(H_n/H_{n-1})$ such that $\beta(1)\ge 2$. By the induction hypothesis, there exists a $\psi\in Irr(H_{n-1})$ with $\psi(1)\ge 2^{n-1}$. To use Corollary 6.17, it suffices to show that $\psi$ is extendable to $H_n$.

Then I got stuck... Any hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. With the same notations in the question we have the following:

Consider $\psi^G$. Note that $\psi^{G}(1)=|G:H_{n-1}|\psi(1)\ge 2^{n}$.

Prove by contradiction. Suppose any irreducible character of $G$ has degree less than $2^{n}$.

Let $\gamma$ be an irreducible constituent of $\psi^G$, that is $[\psi^G,\gamma]_{G}\ge 1$, by the Frobenius reciprocity, we have $$[\psi,\gamma|_{H_{n-1}}\ ]_{H_{n-1}}=[\psi^G,\gamma]_{G}\ge 1. $$

Clifford's theorem gives us $\gamma|_{H_{n-1}}=e\sum_{i=1}^t\psi^{(i)}$ where $e=[\psi^G,\gamma]_G$ and $\psi^{(i)}$ denotes the conjugate of $\psi$.

So $\gamma(1)=et\psi(1)\ge et2^{n-1}$. But $\gamma(1)<2^n$. So $e=t=1$. Thus $\gamma|_{H_{n-1}}=\psi$. And we know that $\psi$ is extendible to $G$. Hence $\gamma\beta(1)\ge 2^{n}$ and $\gamma\beta\in Irr(G)$ by Corollary 6.17 which is a contradiction.

Comment: Yes this is correct, well done, +1 from me.

Comment: Note that the converse is not true: if $G$ has a $\chi \in Irr(G)$ with $\chi(1)=2^n$, then $G$ not necessarily has a normal series with non-abelian quotients of length $n$. Counterexample: $A_5$ has an irreducible complex character of degree $4$.